# Jenkins execution of manage.py runserver

Tags: django, jenkins

I couldn't find information how to get build result from manage.py runserver
It runs contantly and no server log is outputed.

This way I can't execute the next shell commant or trigger the next job.

The only solition I have come to is to use parallel jobs.

Any one here with better idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And just few mins ago my collegue showed me to use nohup and with setting BUILD_ID of Jenkins it would be like this to get Success from the build and still the server running

BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup python manage.py runserver host_server &